# go_router using browser back button extra is null flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-go-router

let's say I navigate from page a with context.push() and pass extra to page b.
then if I navigate to page c and then press the browser back button to go back to page b now extra is null and page shows error.
any solutions?
I think we can use query parameters but it brings up security problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow one of the two possible solution:

1. Dont let page to come back to **B** from **C**, You can use something like `popUntil`
2. When coming back to **B** from **C** override the naviagetion such that you send the extra object along with it. So that **B** has **extra** value

#### Edit:

Presently there is no way to achieve this using `go_router`. You can use [`go_router_flow`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router_flow) which is exactly like `go_router` with this pop with value feature.

```
final bool? result = await context.push<bool>('/page2');

WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  if(result){
    print('Page returned $result');
  }
});
```

Comment: it's not about just going back to page B in every ways. I mean when I press the back button in the app bar every thing works fine but when I press the browser back button I loose the extra.

Comment: Please find my edit. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use the beamer package for routing.This problem occur in the go router.

[beamer package link](https://pub.dev/packages/beamer)